# How to show translated chat window?

Tags: liveagent, translation

I have created few chat buttons and set different language for each of them. However the language field for the button doesn't seem to do anything. Whichever button I try (German, Swedish or Finish) I always have the standard English chat window.

[image]

Is there something else that I need to set set up? I'm not using custom chat pages, so I'm expecting to have translations out of the box. After all Salesforce is supposed to support those languages.

**[Update]**

I noticed that when the chat window opens, the url for this window includes language parameter, but it's empty:
`https://blah.salesforceliveagent.com/content/s/chat?language=#deployment_id=XXX...`. If I manually set the language parameter for example to `de` I get german chat window. So apparently salesforce CAN speak german. The question however remains: how do I tell salesforce to launch the chat window with appropriate language parameter automatically?

**[Update 2]**

I have tried to add `language` parameter to the endpoint url in call to `liveagent.init()` but that causes deployment script to fail miserably (it tries to submit button using relative url) and I end up with chat window showing file not found message generated by my browser.

Comment: Can you share your button config?

Comment: @PepeFloyd There is not much to share. It's just a button with some skills attached and language set to german. Everything else is default.